# Should I put the raw data in the appendix of an investigation if it is available in the GitHub repository?

Tags: data, tables

I am currently doing an investigation (IB Extended Essay if it is helpful) of how different architectural approaches affect website performance. To do so, I have written a program that repeatedly runs a series of tests on each of the three researched websites. I now have 3 tables (as CSV files) with 7 columns and over 100 rows (the tests were run 100 times) stored in a GitHub repo.

In the investigation itself, I am taking the average of these columns and go from there. What I am asking is, should I put the raw data in the appendix? On the one hand, it seems like a good practice to show the data, as it demonstrates where did the averages come from. On the other hand, those tables are massive, AND they can still be accessed in the repository. Should I put it or not?

Comment: What would you gain by including the data? This might depend on the medium in which the paper is published.

Comment: "Supplementary material and raw data is available from ..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to put the data into the paper itself if it is accessible and you point to its location. For a printed paper it is mostly useless, of course, and if it is online, then it is only a click or two away. No one is likely to complain about the minimal added effort.

But, like any other web resources, your reference to it should include a date (last referenced). Then if it is later changed for any reason, the reader will have a better sense of what is going on.